# quarkus/mutiny how to trigger a side job without waiting it

Tags: quarkus, mutiny, quarkus-reactive

quarkus reactive uses mutiny to handle task asynchronously.
But, the flow is always wait every job to finish, then returns the result.
Sometime, I just want to trigger a job and let it run in the background without waiting it to be done.
Any suggestion or example?

```
Uni<Integer> mainJob() {
  // fake logic
  return Uni.createFrom().item(1);
}

Uni<Void> sideJob(int n) {
  // fake logic
  logger.log("result = " + n);
}

@Path("test")
Uni<Integer> testExample() {
    return mainJob().onItem().call(n -> sideJob(n));
}
```

The upper code only returns after sideJob() is done. But, I just want to return the result immediately once mainJob is done, with sideJob triggered and run in background.
Any suggestion on it?

ManagedExecutor may be a way to do but it seems not natural in this case. The side job may/not be long running.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Uni interface documentation:

> To trigger the computation, a UniSubscriber must subscribe to the Uni. It will be notified of the outcome once there is an item or failure event fired by the observed Uni. A subscriber receives (asynchronously) a UniSubscription and can cancel the demand at any time.

Thus, the **only** way to start the execution of a Uni is by **subscribing** to it, even by calling `uni.await().indefinitely()` you are, in fact, subscribing to the Uni as we can see in the documentation of the `indefinitely()` method:

> Subscribes to the Uni and waits (blocking the caller thread) indefinitely until a item event is fired or a failure event is fired by the upstream uni.

Invoking the `call()` method is nothing more than chaining a new function that will be included in the stream that will be executed when the Uni is subscribed. This way, when the `testExample()` method returns the result of the `call()`, it is not executing and waiting for the Uni to finish, it is actually returning the result immediately.

However, whoever is going to receive the final result must wait for the Uni stream to finish, so the client waiting for the HTTP response will be waiting for the `sideJob()` to finish in order to receive the original value, but once again, your `testExample()` method is not waiting for anything, it returns the Uni immediately without waiting for it to be executed.